# Problemas com o loop personalizado Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou desenvolvendo um tema personalizado utilizando bootstrap e não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum criar um loop para exibir meus posts como eu queria.

Eu queria que meus posts seguissem a seguinte ordem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem o único resultado que obtive (fora os loops infinitos rsrs) foi isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui esta a forma como montei o loop:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 text-center titulo-blog">
                <h3 class="page-h3"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <?php $i = 0; ?>

        <?php if (($i % 2 == 0) && have_posts()): ?>
```

```
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 imp-blog">
                            <?php query_posts(array(
                                'category_name' => 'imp',
                            )); ?>
                            <?php while (have_posts()): the_post();  ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <div class="hoverzoom img-responsive">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        <div class="retina">

                                            <div class="ret-text">
                                                <p class="ret-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                                <p class="ret-sub"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></p>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 img-blog">


                            <?php query_posts(array(
                                'category_name' => 'img',
                            )); ?>
                            <?php while (have_posts()): the_post();  ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <div class="hoverzoom img-responsive">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        <div class="retina">
                                            <div class="ret-text">
                                                <p class="ret-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                                <p class="ret-sub"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <? else: ?>
```

```
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">


                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 img-blog ">


                            <?php query_posts(array(
                                'category_name' => 'img',
                            )); ?>
                            <?php while (have_posts()): the_post();  ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <div class="hoverzoom img-responsive">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        <div class="retina">

                                            <div class="ret-text">
                                                <p class="ret-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                                <p class="ret-sub"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></p>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 imp-blog">


                            <?php query_posts(array(
                                'category_name' => 'imp',
                            )); ?>
                            <?php while (have_posts()): the_post();  ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <div class="hoverzoom img-responsive">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        <div class="retina">
                                            <div class="ret-text">
                                                <p class="ret-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                                <p class="ret-sub"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php $i++; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

obs: eu defino quais imagens serão as grandes e quais serão as pequenas pelas categorias do wordpress

obs2: eu criei um if na qual se "i" for par ele segue a primeira ordem, caso contrario ele segue a ordem inversa.

Por favor me ajudem não tenho mais ideia de como resolver isso sem alterar o layout

Comment: O problema não é seu loop, o que você quer não é feito puramente com html e css até onde eu sei. O que você quer é usar uma biblioteca javascript tipo o Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: realmente não é feito somente com html e css, eu preferia não utilizar biblioteca, queria se possível somente com php....mas quando fiz com contadores eu entrava em loops infinitos.

Comment: O problema é que você não tem como saber o tamanho da tela do cara, né? Você até pode saber qual o tamanho das suas caixas, mesmo assim pode dar xabu.

Comment: as imagens teriam uma altura padrão, e com relação a largura o bootstrap iria resolver.

Comment: Amigo use o plugin Photo Gallery

Comment: eu não queria usar plugin... não vejo necessidade pra isso